# Chrome add-on to download YouTube videos

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, youtube

Any add-on for Chrome browser to download YouTube videos?

Comment: Both answers are great, hard to pick a winner.

Comment: I think the advantage of my answer is that it uses less memory, and the advantage of Sathya's solution is that it will get updated automatically and synced across browsers with your Google account.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[I use this Greasemonkey userscript.](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/62634)

[image: Download Youtube video]

Answer (score 4):

[YouTube downloader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ilnhhknmgbapamkajmabgilknngopiok) works well.

> Download any video as 240p*(FLV), 360p*(FLV,MP4,WebM**), 480p*(FLV), 720p*(MP4,WebM*), 1080p*(MP4) and Original*(MP4).
>
> How to use:
>
> - Below the video, you'll see an download button. Click it, and then, a pop-up menu will appear. Select the quality that you want.

[image]

Comment: link is no longer working

Comment: Link's dead again, use [Chrome YouTube Downloader](http://www.chromeextensions.org/utilities/chrome-youtube-downloader/)

Answer (score 0):

Hands down the best Google Chrome addon for YouTube I've ever used it YousableTubeFix.

[image]

Some of the handy features:

- Download a video with a single click **directly** from the video page.
- Select a default quality for every video. (Why doesn't YouTube have a working version of this I don't know).
- Select a default video window size. Very handy if you have a large monitor and want to use your real estate.
- Prevent auto-play but keep auto-buffer.
- much more awesome features...

Read more about what it does on my personal page:

http://sergiotapia.me/upgrade-youtube-with-downloads-quality-options-and-more-using-yousabletubefix/